# Why responsive utilities in tailwindcss is showing opposite output

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Why `sm` responsive utility in tailwindcss is showing the opposite output. I believed that using `sm` is to do something in small devices and smaller devices, however, the `sm` only applied in medium devices.
Any idea?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="hidden md:block">
      Your device is medium/large [hidden md:block].
    </h1>
    <p class="md:hidden">
      Your device is small [md:hidden].
    </p>

    <h3 class="sm:block hidden">
      Your device is small too [sm:block hidden].
    </h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-star-gfbk5l?file=/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tailwind you should first target mobile devices (like always recommended, since most of clients use mobile). 
So general style like `bg-red-500` would apply to every screen size, and the media queries (e.g `sm`), would apply to every screen which is **larger** than the specified screen size.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<pre class="text-red-500 sm:text-blue-500">
What it looks like: This text is red on smaller than 640px screen widths (mobile) and blue on others. 


The exact definition: This text is red on all devices but blue on bigger than 640px screen widths) </pre>
```

Source:

> Mobile First By default, Tailwind uses a mobile first breakpoint
> system, similar to what you might be used to in other frameworks like
> Bootstrap.
>
> What this means is that unprefixed utilities (like uppercase) take
> effect on all screen sizes, while prefixed utilities (like
> md:uppercase) only take effect at the specified breakpoint and above.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

Comment: Now, everything is clear to me finally after 1 week of thinking about it.

Comment: @Jie yeah, I was surprised too when I first learned that, but it makes more sense since mobile devices are more common